# Item Respawn time in Dragon Quest IX

Tags: dragon-quest-9

So I've been trying to build a store of source materials to build some items in game using Alchemy, but I've found it hard to get items on the game map to respawn.

What is the spawn rate for items?  I assume it's different for different items, but I've been unable to find anything concrete out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spawn rates are definitely different for different items, and it is based on in game play time, not real time.  Also, the item spawn timer resets every time you save at a church and exit the game, so you should always exit the game via quick save.

While this sounds like you can easily lose all your progress if something bad happens (like batteries running out), there is an easy solution:

Save at a church, then choose to continue your adventures, and then quick save to exit the game.